# Bootstrap4 Disabled button white instead of supposed color

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am using a bootstrap button on one of my page, that is disabled, and the styling seems to not be working properly

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<button disabled class="btn btn-primary">suivant</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary disabled">suivant</button>
```

I tried these 2 ways and the result look like this for both approach: [initial look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Y98g.png) || [on Mouse over](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccKnP.png)

EDIT: Important to mention that i only have bootstrap4, no personnal style sheet and no other themes

This is a react Project, className is used instead of class

Comment: what are you expecting it to look like? it looks like the bootstrap example https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/buttons/#disabled-state https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/EmpdyK

Comment: @MichaelCoker the button only looks the way reflected on the documentation on mouse over, rest of the time is white and empty, like the first Screenshot

Comment: *"Important to mention that i only have bootstrap4, no personnal style sheet and no other themes"* obviously you have something if it doesn't look like the codepen I posted or the bootstrap example.

Comment: Updated your post with the bootstrap css file. Do those buttons display like you expect or no?

Comment: @MichaelCoker somebody else indeed included another stylesheet that wasnt used, but modified the appearance of a disabled button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://codepen.io/jacobweyer/pen/ybqxBK

I've updated this codepen to show Bootstrap4 buttons with BS4 alpha 6. They look like they show up as intended in and outside of React.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary">suivant</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" disabled>suivant disabled</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another stylesheet was making conflict with bootstrap that i wasnt aware of

thanks to @MichaelCoker for making me search trough my project again